# PHP error - parse/unexpected t-string in sitemap

Tags: php

Our website unexpectedly starting giving the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home3/rslade/public_html/wp-content/plugins/kocuj-sitemap/kocuj-sitemap.php on line 51

```
48 // initialize classes
49 $kocujSitemapPluginDir = dirname(__FILE__);
50 include $kocujSitemapPluginDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'classes'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'base.class.php';
51 \KocujSitemapPlugin\Classes\Base::getInstance(__FILE__);
52 include $kocujSitemapPluginDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'autoload.php';
53 unset($kocujSitemapPluginDir);
```

We had someone do our site and they bailed so I'm hoping to be able to fix the error myself and so far I've not been able to figure out the cause so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edited to add - here is the remainder of the code in the file after the general information regarding the author of the plugin

```
 /**
 * kocuj-sitemap.php
 *
 * @author Dominik Kocuj <dominik@kocuj.pl>
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU General Public License v2 or later
* @copyright Copyright (c) 2013-2016 Dominik Kocuj
 * @package kocuj_sitemap
 */

// security
if ((!defined('ABSPATH')) || ((isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) && (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) === basename(__FILE__)))) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    die();
}

// meta translation
if (1 === 0) {
    _e('This plugin adds shortcode, widget and PHP function that prepares the sitemap which contains links to all of your posts, pages, menu items, authors, tags and custom types entries in the place where it is located. It supports excluding the selected entries. It also supports multilingual websites (by using qTranslate X plugin if exists). The sitemap is automatically generated and stored in the cache to speeds up the loading of sitemap on your website.', 'kocuj-sitemap');
}

// initialize classes
$kocujSitemapPluginDir = dirname(__FILE__);
include $kocujSitemapPluginDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'classes'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'base.class.php';
\KocujSitemapPlugin\Classes\Base::getInstance(__FILE__);
include $kocujSitemapPluginDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'autoload.php';
unset($kocujSitemapPluginDir);

/**
 * Display sitemap
 *
 * @access public
 * @param string $homeLinkText Home link text in the sitemap - default: empty
 * @param string $class Sitemap class - default: empty
 * @param array $exclude List of elements to exclude - it is divided into sections: "post", "category", "author", "term" - default: empty
 * @return void
 */
function kocujsitemap_show_sitemap($homeLinkText = '', $class = '', array $exclude = array()) {
    // show sitemap
    echo \KocujSitemapPlugin\Classes\Sitemap::getInstance()->get($homeLinkText, $class, $exclude);
}
```

Comment: 51 line is incorrect. either include or variable needed there

Comment: @Anant That's not terribly helpful. The question makes it clear that's the offending line, but not *why*

Comment: Thanks, the error message told me line 51 is incorrect.  I've researched other t-string errors and they indicate misplaced apostrophes and/or quotation errors and line 51 has neither.  Do you have insight on how to fix it or insight as to how the error happened in that the file was not changed recently?

Comment: Please post what `echo __FILE__;` is, as well as the function `\KocujSitemapPlugin\Classes\Base::getInstance`

Answer (score 0):

I communicated with the plugin author via the WP forums and he suggested that My PHP needed updating.  I updated it and the site is back up.

Thanks